# How can I change the default virtual environment command in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, virtual-environment

I have setup a virtual environment in my project folder using Command Palette: Python: Create Environment: .venv
So whenever I open vs code in that folder it attempts to start the environment using .venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1 file which fails as running scripts is disabled for Powershell. So I want to switch to command prompt as default terminal and execute .venv/Scripts/Activate.bat by default instead.

I am able to switch default terminal to cmd but vs code still tries to run the .venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1 instead of .venv/Scripts/Activate.bat. How do I switch this default command from

```
& <file-path>/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

to

```
<file-path>/.venv/Scripts/Activate.bat
```

**Edit:**
So I want to be more clear about the issue...

- The activate environment is set as true
- ["python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nepan.png)
- And the default terminal is set as Command Prompt
- ["terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lE6.png)
- When I have my project opened in vscode and create a new terminal whether cmd or powershell, vscode runs the proper command to run the virtual environment properly.
- [New terminal created by either +'plus' icon or View->Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXSxd.png)
- However, when I open the project using File->Open Folder or start vscode in that folder, then vscode automatically starts a terminal and tries to run the virtual environment. However, as the default terminal is cmd, Command Prompt starts but vscode tries to run the environment using the powershell command. I have to run the command manually or open a new terminal for it to run the proper command
- [Terminal opened by default on starting vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y654Z.png)

I have no problem running the command again manually or creating a new terminal, but this error really bugs me. Hope this helps clear the problem.

Comment: based on the terminal VSC select 1 of the 3 activate scripts, most likely your default terminal is not `cmd`, close VSC, open VSC, press `Ctrl+backtick`, do you get powershell or cmd

Comment: why don't you enable running of scripts in Powershell?

Comment: @rioV8 I get cmd by following the steps. Also, I checked Terminal › Integrated › Default Profile: Windows, and it is set as a command prompt. If I allow running scripts in Powershell, won't it enable the feature for all sources? I thought it was disabled for a reason, so I didn't attempt that.

Comment: Also, I found that closing the terminal only and opening it again runs the correct command, but it is not the case at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose a virtual environment interpreter, vscode will automatically activate the environment every time you build a new terminal. This is controlled by the following settings, and the default value is true.

```
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
```

[image]

The shell command that activates the virtual environment is based on your terminal automatic change:

- PowerShell is `& e:/workspace/py12/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`

  [image]
- CMD is `e:/workspace/py12/.venv/Scripts/activate.bat`

  [image]

As for you every time you build a new terminal, you will create a new PowerShell or CMD, which is controlled by the following settings

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

[image]

Comment: That's the thing, whenever I create a new terminal, it runs the correct command but when I open the project in a new vs code window, it opens a new cmd terminal as I set it as default but tries to run the PowerShell command to activate the environment. 
I can attach images if it helps in explanation.
Can this be some sort of bug?

Comment: Do you mean that your machine uses the PowerShell command to activate the virtual environment in CMD? Then there was an error message and failed?


If you don't mind, describe your operation steps step by step. It is better to show screenshots.

Comment: Yes that is whats going on. I have added the steps and screenshots. Do these help understand the issue?

Comment: Did you use the `***.psl` command before opening a new vscode window? Adding the `"terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,` [configuration](https://imgur.com/ymp9XXj.png) to your *settings.json* should do the trick.